# skip the first line of input file with awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to use this script to extract data from some input files. The problem is that the input file has a header on the first line and this line appears in the result also. The script does what it is supposed to do. How can I skip the first line of the input file?

```
#!/bin/awk -f 
NF == 3 {               ## 3-fields - heading row
if (FNR>1)                ## not 1st row
print ""                ##  output newline
printf "%d", ++n          ## output counter 1, 2, 3, ...
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)     ## loop over each heading
printf "  %s", $i       ##  output with 2-leading spaces
next                      ## skip to next record
}

{
  printf "%s", $0           ## output all recs until next heading
}
END {
  print ""                  ## END rule - tidy up with newline.
}
```

I have tried with this:

```
#!/bin/awk -f 
NR>1{
NF == 3 {               ## 3-fields - heading row
if (FNR>1)                ## not 1st row
print ""                ##  output newline
printf "%d", ++n          ## output counter 1, 2, 3, ...
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)     ## loop over each heading
printf "  %s", $i       ##  output with 2-leading spaces
next                      ## skip to next record
}

{
  printf "%s", $0           ## output all recs until next heading
}
}
END {
  print ""                  ## END rule - tidy up with newline.
}
```

But it isn't the right syntax.

An input example is below:

```
 &plot nbnd=  60, nks=    93 /
            0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  -44.871  -44.869  -21.466  -21.462  -21.364  -21.275  -21.275  -21.271   -6.942   -6.316
   -5.786   -5.623   -5.519   -5.488   -4.009   -3.947   -3.935   -3.935   -3.927   -3.886
   -3.822   -3.723   -3.691   -3.661    4.013    5.337    6.511    7.180    7.181    7.730
    7.755    7.826    8.312    8.450    8.932    8.932    9.076    9.157    9.397    9.542
    9.633    9.909    9.909   11.553   13.243   14.431   14.431   14.547   14.566   14.914
   15.137   16.017   16.135   16.410   17.399   17.960   18.076   18.319   19.480   19.480
            0.000000  0.100000  0.000000
  -44.871  -44.869  -21.466  -21.462  -21.364  -21.277  -21.275  -21.273   -6.928   -6.303
   -5.783   -5.621   -5.517   -5.492   -4.007   -3.940   -3.938   -3.934   -3.928   -3.888
   -3.820   -3.721   -3.690   -3.659    3.993    5.281    6.513    7.189    7.191    7.645
    7.766    7.901    8.255    8.447    8.922    8.934    9.017    9.216    9.401    9.543
    9.674    9.869    9.915   11.517   13.293   14.377   14.421   14.434   14.706   14.913
   15.138   16.093   16.158   16.424   17.461   17.957   18.043   18.282   19.271   19.450
            0.000000  0.200000  0.000000
  -44.871  -44.869  -21.466  -21.461  -21.363  -21.283  -21.280  -21.274   -6.888   -6.266
   -5.773   -5.613   -5.510   -5.505   -4.001   -3.947   -3.934   -3.929   -3.920   -3.892
   -3.816   -3.714   -3.685   -3.654    3.933    5.132    6.519    7.210    7.222    7.539
    7.761    7.991    8.095    8.443    8.879    8.937    8.941    9.377    9.402    9.539
```

If the input is saved in an `input.dat` I run the awk script as follows:

```
./script.awk input.dat > output.dat
```

I keep reading the documentation for awk but I just do not understand the structure of these scripts (like the one above). They look really different from the

```
BEGIN {

}
{

}
END {

}
```

structure. I am so lost with awk and I know my questions are annoying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> skip the first line of input file with awk

Use `FNR==1{next}` as first pattern-action, applying this to your first code gives

```
#!/bin/awk -f
FNR==1{next}
NF == 3 {               ## 3-fields - heading row
print ""                ##  output newline
printf "%d", ++n          ## output counter 1, 2, 3, ...
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)     ## loop over each heading
printf "  %s", $i       ##  output with 2-leading spaces
next                      ## skip to next record
}

{
  printf "%s", $0           ## output all recs until next heading
}
END {
  print ""                  ## END rule - tidy up with newline.
}
```

Comment: yay! that is the solution!